# xmllint how to read xml file that has android sharedpreferences values

Tags: xml, shell, xpath, xmllint

I need to get a value from a sharedPreference file in android. The xml for the file looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <boolean name="apples" value="true" />
    <boolean name="grapes" value="true" />
    <boolean name="oranges" value="true" />
</map>
```

and the file name is fruits.xml

how can i use xmllint in a shell script to retrieve the value of grapes ?

I've tried `xmllint fruits.xml` and then `xmllint xpath map/grapes` but its not working. I want the final output to just be "true" as this is the value of grapes.

Comment: `map/boolean[@name="grapes"]/@value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct name for this option in xmllint is `--xpath` and there must be quotes (`"`) around the path expression:

```
$ xmllint --xpath "string(/map/boolean[@name = 'grapes']/@value)" fruit.xml
true
```

If you were using `/map/boolean[@name = 'grapes']/@value` without the string function around it, xmllint would return the whole attribute: `value="true"`.

If you are unsure about an option simply type

```
$ xmllint
```

without any arguments. This will bring up the help and list, among other things:

> --xpath expr: evaluate the XPath expression, imply --noout

I am on Mac OS X, using the following version of xmllint:

```
$ xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20902
```